# QT C++ QCursor::pos() threads error

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, cursor-position

I am using Ubuntu  12.10 and QT 5.
This is the code of a run() method of a class inherited from QThread

```
void CheckIdleThread::run()
{
    while(isAlive())
    {
        bool newIdle = idle;
        QPoint newPos = QCursor::pos();
        if(newPos != oldPos)
        {
            if(idle)
                newIdle = false;
        }else{
            if(!idle)
                newIdle = true;
        }


        if(newIdle != idle)
            emit(isIdleChanged(idle));
        idle = newIdle;

        sleep(refreshRate);
    }

}
```

and it produces this error  "Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0."

And it appears to be a problem with QCursor::pos() resource.

- What is the problem in details?
- How could I solve this problem?
- Is there an easier way to detect if a user is not interacting with the PC for a while?

Comment: QCursor, as a part of QtGui is just not thread safe. Do not call `QCursor::pos()` from additional thread.

Comment: So is there any thread safe substitute of it, or a certain operation to do to make it thread safe?

Comment: I'd propose to call some `slot` of an object, that belong to main thread with `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` to obtain result, but it will cause you get result only after next message processing in the GUI thread, i.e. not immediately. I'll elaborate if you agree with such limitation.

Comment: @Ahmed Farag: is there a specific reason, why this code should be executed in a different thread with sleep? I don't see any long instructions, so I suggest you to move it to main thread and use timer. Though, it does not solve the main problem - detecting that the user is not interacting with PC - 'cause you don't track the keyboard.

Comment: You could trigger slot on QTimer with `refreshRate` interval.